# How to return the first highest value that is placed in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
dic = {}
count = 0
i = 0
str_in = str_in.replace(' ','')
while i < len(str_in):
    count = str_in.count(str_in[i])
    dic[str_in[i]] = count
    i += 1
for key in dic:
    if key == max(dic, key=dic.get):
        return key
        break
```

The dictionary that is made in this program is

```
{'i': 1, 'h': 2, 'j': 2, 'o': 2, 'n': 1, 's': 2}
```

from the input `'joshin josh'`

I am pretty sure the dictionary's max value returns h because it is the first value in the dictionary with the highest value, even if tied.
I want it to return j because that is the first letter I put into the dictionary. It seems like the dictionary automatically sorts the letters alphabetically, which I also don't understand. I want this to work with any string and all tied letters, not just this particular string. Correct me if I am wrong on anything, I am a noob.

Comment: Use an OrderedDict or wait for python 3.6 to get dict ordered by default

Comment: To expound on @Boud's comment, a normal python dictionary has no order intrinsically- if order is important, you need a different data structure, like an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: @Boud - Dicts will be ordered in Python 3.6?!

Comment: @linusg: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html

Comment: That's so cool, @ajcr - thanks for the link!

Comment: You can subclass counter and ordereddict and make an ordered counter. Raymond hettinger did it in his super considered super talk at pycon.

Comment: `dict`s will be ordered in Python 3.6, but this is an implementation detail. The language itself does not require order except in very limited circumstances (`**kwargs` being one) and Python implementations other than CPython (the reference implementation) may or may not implement it. You should continue using `collections.OrderedDict` if you *require* dict items in insertion order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, by using `OrderedDict` as a mixin class it allows an ordered `Counter` class to be easily composed. You can then use the first entry of the list returned from the `most_common` method.

e.g.

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

oc = OrderedCounter('joshin josh')
print(oc.most_common()[0])
```

Will give you back a tuple of the letter and the number of occurrences. e.g.

> ('j', 2)

You'd need to protect the `[0]` in the case where you were passing an empty string, Where nothing is most common.

To better understand why this works I recommend watching Raymond Hettingers Super Considered Super talk from PyCon 2015. Youtube link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manually count, you could use Python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count letter occurrences, find the max, then return the first letter in your string that matches that count:

```
from collections import Counter

string = 'joshin josh'
counts = Counter(string)
max_count = max(counts.values())
print(next(c for c in string if counts[c] == max_count))  # j
```

`next(c for c in string if letter_counts[c] == max_count)` returns the first letter in the given string for which the count is the max count.

**A more optimal approach**:

The previous approach would have you traverse the string in the worst case three times. For a one-pass approach, it would be most efficient to just keep track of the max count and letter corresponding to it as you iterate through the string:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
max_letter = None
max_count = 0
string = 'joshin josh'
for c in string:
    counts[c] += 1
    if counts[c] > max_count:
        max_letter = c
        max_count = counts[c]

print(max_letter)  # j
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OrderedDict`

Just a simple change would resolve your problem

```
ord_dic = OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: str_in.index(t[0])))
```

So you could use something like

```
dic = {}
count = 0
i = 0
str_in = str_in.replace(' ','')
while i < len(str_in):
    count = str_in.count(str_in[i])
    dic[str_in[i]] = count
    i += 1
ord_dic = OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: str_in.index(t[0])))
for key in ord_dic:
    if key == max(ord_dic, key=ord_dic.get):
        return key
        break
```

Do not forget to import `OrderedDict` 
Add this line at the top of your code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Comment: I tried this before you posted and after, I get the error global name 'OrderedDict' is not defined. Do i have to import a library to use it?

Comment: Thank you so much, hopefully your answer helps out other people possibly!

Comment: This answer doesn't require an `OrderedDict` at all. The ordered dict could very well be replaced with a list.